# How to take script in MySQL Workbench 6.0?

Tags: scripting, mysql-workbench

I want to take script of tables, stored procedures, functions & so on. in MySQL Workbench 6.0. I couldn't find the option exists like in SQL Server. How to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "want to take db script"? Do you want to export the SQL script for a db object or want to dump your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the navigator window at the left of the screen, click on management tab. Click on Data Export Link.

For more info visit 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html